# Custom policy: Invalidate B2C session after account deletion

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a custom policy to allow users to delete their accounts, following something similar to https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/delete-my-account/policy/DeleteMyAccount.xml

If we then invoke another custom policy the B2C session is still active.  The technical profile below still pulls out the old (deleted) objectId.

```
     <TechnicalProfile Id="SM-AAD">
      <DisplayName>Session Mananagement Provider</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.SSO.DefaultSSOSessionProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
      </PersistedClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectIdFromSession" DefaultValue="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

I see references to invalidateAllRefreshTokens invalidating the browser session, but then see many discussion saying this is not the case.

If there still not a way to invalidate the session, or call logout from a custom policy.

Thanks
Nigel.

Comment: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/revoke-sso-sessions